Missing category in reference level in multinomial GAM with mgcv in R
Consider the multinomial GAM with mgcv in R
library(mgcv)

multinom = gam(list(sound ~ word + s(long, lat),
                          ~ word + s(long, lat),
                          ~ word + s(long, lat),
                          ~ word + s(long, lat),
                          ~ word + s(long, lat)),
                          data=pronunciation, method="ML", optimizer="efs", family=multinom(K=5))

sound (numeric 0–5) and word are 6 categories each. I need word 1 as reference level but word 1 does not feature sound 3 (i.e., 0 occurances). The model only works with optimizer="efs" and optimizer=c("outer","bfgs") but gives unrealistic results for the missing sound category in the reference level.
Is there a way to overcome this issue by not changing the reference level to a word that features all sound categories?
Simulating my data and replacing sound 3 (numeric 2) by sound 4 (numeric 3) in word 1 (alpha) so that the reference level (word 1; alpha) lacks sound 3 (numeric 2)
sound         <- sample(0:5, size=960, replace=T)
word          <- as.factor(rep(c('alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo', 'foxtrot'), each=4))
age           <- as.factor(rep(c('young', 'old'), times=480))
gender        <- as.factor(rep(c('female', 'female', 'male', 'male'), times=240))
long          <- rep(c(runif(40)), each=24)
lat           <- rep(c(runif(40)), each=24)
pronunciation <- data.frame(sound, word, age, gender, long, lat)

pronunciation$sound[pronunciation$word == "alpha" & pronunciation$sound == 2] = 3


You should provide a reproducible example of your data set to help people reproduce your issue.

The mgcv documentation says "Missing categories are not supported." (p 163). So is this the answer to the question or is there something I can do?
